# How to bind datagridview to data in a class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a problem to bind the data from class to datagridview in C# Winform

I created a 3 classes, it is invoice class, SoldItem class and Item class
one of the public member of invoice class is a list.
inside solditem, there are 2 public member named int quantitysold and Item itemsold

Then I have a datagridview which already has names for all of its column.
I want to display the information from the invoice object, after few days I still could not figure out how to do that.

I have tried this:

lblDate.Text = invoice.InvoiceDate.ToString();
customer.Text = invoice.Customer;
but dont know how to relate data from invoice object to datagridview.

Here is my class definitioan, form, and function.

```
class Item
    {
        public string? ItemName { get; set; }
        public double? SellingPrice { get; set; }
        public Item(string itemName, double sellingPrice)
        {
            ItemName = itemName;
            SellingPrice = sellingPrice;
        }
    }
    class SoldItem
    {
        public int QuantitySold { get; set; }
        public Item ItemSold { get; set; }
        public SoldItem(int quantitySold, Item itemSold) {
            QuantitySold = quantitySold;
            ItemSold = itemSold;
        }
    }
    class Invoice
    {
        public DateTime InvoiceDate{ get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public BindingList<SoldItem>? ListSoldItem { get; set; }
        public Invoice() { }
    }

// form
// 
// dgv
// 
this.dgv.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
    this.Item,
    this.Quantity,
    this.Price,
    this.LineTotal});


    this.Item.HeaderText = "Item Description";
    this.Item.Name = "Item";
    this.Quantity.HeaderText = "Quantity";
    this.Quantity.Name = "Quantity";
    this.Price.HeaderText = "Price";
    this.Price.Name = "Price";
    this.Price.ReadOnly = true;
    this.LineTotal.HeaderText = "Line Total";
    this.LineTotal.Name = "LineTotal";


private void setupForm() {

Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            invoice.InvoiceDate = DateTime.Now;
            invoice.Customer = "Frank";
            invoice.ListSoldItem = new BindingList<SoldItem>()
            {
                new (2, new ("Item A", 10)),
                new (4, new ("Item B", 50)),
                new (7, new ("Item C", 150)),
                new (2, new ("Item D", 1000)),
                new (4, new ("Item E", 5)),
                new (7, new ("Item F", 15))
            };

            lblDate.Text = invoice.InvoiceDate.ToString();
            customer.Text = invoice.Customer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the datasource property of the datagridview.

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.InvoiceDate = DateTime.Now;
invoice.Customer = "Frank";
invoice.ListSoldItem = new BindingList<SoldItem>()
{
    new (2, new ("Item A", 10)),
    new (4, new ("Item B", 50)),
    new (7, new ("Item C", 150)),
    new (2, new ("Item D", 1000)),
    new (4, new ("Item E", 5)),
    new (7, new ("Item F", 15))
};

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = invoice.ListSoldItem;
```

Columns of datagrid is defined by object properties.
For example, to have a column "Total", you must create a new object property which return the price total. something like that:

```
class SoldItem
{
    [DisplayName("Quantity")]
    public int QuantitySold { get; set; }
    public Item ItemSold { get; set; }
    public SoldItem(int quantitySold, Item itemSold)
    {
        QuantitySold = quantitySold;
        ItemSold = itemSold;
    }

    public double? Total => QuantitySold * ItemSold.SellingPrice;
}
```

the attribut DisplayName change the column header.

Moreover to display the name of the item instead of WinFormsApp1.Item, you have to modify the class Item by adding a method to override ToString().

```
class Item
{
    public string? ItemName { get; set; }
    public double? SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public Item(string itemName, double sellingPrice)
    {
        ItemName = itemName;
        SellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ItemName;
    }
}
```

The result :
[image]

Comment: I tried this.dgv.DataSource = invlice.ListSoldItem,
the result is there are 2 new column appear at the table, column QuantitySold and ItemSold. In column QuantitySold all the value is WinFormsApp1.Item

But if I set dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
Nothing happen

Comment: If you set auto-generate columns to false then you must define your column headers

Comment: I updated my answer, I think this is the result you expect, isn't it?

Comment: I modify my code following your suggestion, it works but not 100% solve my problem. the name column header of the grid is displaying the variable name from the class, what I need is showing like Quantity instead of QuantitySold. So I managed to add "DataPropertyName" property value of each column in the designer. But this approach is not 100% work, because the Price column is still empty.

Comment: The attribut DisplayName change the column header.

Comment: why the column Price is still empty and how to make it filled with SellingPrice?

Comment: In the class SoldItem, you can add a new property returning the price.
public double Price => ItemSold.SellingPrice